# Combine multiple routes to code split bundles

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, code-splitting

In my create-react-app (CRA) application I was easily able to setup route-based code-splitting by following the official guide https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting

Now I could separate every single route into its own JS chunk but I would rather create 2 different bundles (one for the public area of my homepage, one with all pages for logged in users).

How would I separate my application into these two bundles? (I am still using react-router v3)

Edit: My routes are setup like this:

```
<Route
    path="/onepage/:id"
    component={RequireAuth(props => <Component1 {...props} />)}
/>
<Route
    path="/anotherpage"
    component={RequireAuth(props => <Component2 {...props} />)}
/>
```

Is it possible to wrap them in a higher level route (without changing the paths itself) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any and all of my code-splitting needs, I have used `react-loadable`.

You might want to try just splitting every route. Doesn't need to hurt much. <s>But if that is too granular you can always wrap a higher level Route component.</s>

This won't actually work I just realized. In React Router v3 the Routes aren't actually components, just configuration. So your only good option is to wrap all the page level components.

Comment: The higher level Route component would work. I added two example routes to my original question. Can you tell me how to wrap those?

Comment: Edited my answer. In v3 the Route aren't real components you can render. So you can't wrap them with `react-loadable` (or any other dynamic import`)